# Running as Java Application, but not on Server

Tags: spring, maven, web, dynamic

Hello I get some code of a web chat from internet. This projects runs as java application but not on server (in a dynamic web project). How can I make it work on server?

Some useful information:
String boot, 
Maven,
Apache tomcat,
Dynamic web project

POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>chat</groupId>
<artifactId>chat</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>spring-boot-websocket-chat</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

main class:

```
package com.javainuse;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootChatApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(
             SpringBootChatApplication.class , args);
}
}
```

Comment: Didn't quite understand, you want to be able to deploy your app to the servlet container?

Comment: There is an [official guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/) for this.

Comment: The thing is I can run it as java application(and the application is correctly executed in localhost:8080), but when I click in run on server(apache tomcat) the application does not work. I want to be able to run it in the second way. I don't really know if that means to deploy it in the servlet container.

Comment: I took it as java maven project, and now I have made a dynamic web project with the same code.

Answer (score 0):

Change your app packaging to war ! `<packaging>war</packaging>`
And now you can deploy your war in your Server

Comment: do you know how to deploy a war in tomcat ?